# Unable to import package lib.NextBus

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a custom package that I am using for a python project that won't load for some reason. My structure is as follows:

```
ParentFolder
|-.gitignore
|-ReadMe.md
|-requirements.txt
|-setup.py
|-lib
  |-__init__.py
  |-NextBus.py
|-src
  |-Scheduler.py
```

the init function is empty and serves only to allow Python to view lib as a package directory. The import statement in Scheduler.py looks like this:

```
import lib.NextBus as nb
```

I tried another import statement that looked like this:

```
from lib.NextBus import *
```

which also issued the same error.

I am getting a pylint error that says "unable to import lib.NextBus", however in my IDE (VSCode) when I go to type the import statement it correctly autofills the statement, which makes me think that pylint knows that the package should be in lib. I wasn't able to uncover much more about my error as the NextBus code is custom written. Hopefully someone can help...?

Comment: This might not be the correct answer to your question. But VSCode always gave me import problems. Switched to pycharm community.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: I tried running your code using VSCode 1.30.2 using python 3.6. Runs without error